Is it possible to create a constant with a range of values?
I have a condition like this:
        if (value in 0..10 || value in 20..30 || value in 40..50) {
            //do something
        }

I wanted to put these range of values in a constant or something else that looks cleaner, I tried
const val values = {
    0..10
    20..30
    40..50
}

but I get the error Const 'val' has type '() -> IntRange'. Only primitives and String are allowed
Is there a way to do this or do you have any other suggestion?

The corrent syntax for an Array<IntRange> would be [0..10, 20..30, 40..50]; note the square brackets and commas. But even then it can't be a const.

BTW, if in your real case ranges are always such regular, then please be aware this is pretty much the same as: value % 20 <= 10.

You can use something like this.
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(0..10, 20..30, 40..50);
    val value = 22;
    if (list.any { value in it }) {
          println("Hello, world!!!")
      }
}

I can only think of this way to combine the logic. But your way is already simple enough.

Using a set instead of a list is generally better if the goal is to do an in check.

@Joffrey how would that work? A set containing ranges can't be queried like <range> in <set> because you don't know what the range is, until you find one in the set that includes the value, and that can only be done by iteration, and iterating a list is faster.

Oh you're right, I read too quickly and thought the code was querying whether a range is in the set of ranges.
